# Action not found in controller. Using Zend framework but action IS there

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a controller called Account and an action called logout. It's pretty simple:

```
<?php
    class AccountController extends CustomControllerAction
    {    

    public function logoutAction()
    {
        Zend_Auth::getInstance()->clearIdentity();
        $this->_redirect('/account/login');
    }
```

But for some reason I'm getting a uncaught exception

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpweb20/include/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:248 Stack trace: #0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpweb20/include/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpweb20/htdocs/index.php(67): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #2 {main} thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpweb20/include/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php on line 248
```

I'm not having a problem with any other actions or controllers. my loginAction works fine. My registerAction works fine....

Anyone know why this is happening?

Jonesy

Comment: The error says it failed trying to find the _error_ controller. This controller hands all exceptions by default, so it'd be worth adding this so you can see what your actual problem is. See the ErrorHandler section at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html

Comment: @Tim Posted my answer before I saw your comment. If you want to post it yourself just say so I<ll erase mine no problems you were faster.

Comment: @Tim thanks for your response, I've created an error controller to log the errors and it seems i'm getting a "Cannot send headers; headers already sent" error. I'm unsure how to go about redirecting now

Comment: Try using gotoSimple... but Headers already sent means you've echoed something out already, try checking your customcontroller isn't doing anything it shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a error controller.If you look at the [quickstart](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) zf structure you will see it.